# fail to authenticate after deployment

Tags: authentication, glassfish, jaas

I have a web application using glassfish and form authentication (j_security_check). All the passwords and usernames are stored in a javaDB (derby). I was able to log into the system while developing on the localhost and now that I deployed the app to AWS whenever I try to log in with a user (I have checked that the user actually exists in the DB), I always get the same error (that i normally get when entering wrong details) i.e. `WEB9102: Web Login Failed: com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.common.LoginException: Login failed`.
Any ideas what it might be? I don't even know what info to provide since the issue doesn't even throw an exception or something. thanks

Comment: A common issue I face is that during deployment, the Security Realm is not created on the production instance/cluster. I eventually [scripted this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2435/ggkuk.html#ggnca) :)

Comment: OMG that's it I think. I completely missed that!!!